# Where to ask "which technology to use" questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked a question, which unfortunately got an on-hold label!

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139224/which-game-engine-to-build-for-arm-linux-target

Putting an **on-hold** label and saying that *"you shouldn't ask this question here"* is not enough. You should say *"Ask this question at X forum instead"* to help the user.

Now please help me: Where exactly can I ask this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please keep in mind that the on-hold/close infobox is applied automatically when enough users vote to close the question. It can't be modified to address every single question and why they've been closed. Instead, it gives a way to the user to see why the question has been closed and by linking to the help center.

By following the links, there is an answer to your question, right there, in the help center:

By clicking on the first [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) link, then visiting the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section, you'll find the *Where can I ask subjective, discussion, and other questions not fit for this site?* page section:

> - [Our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19)
> - Reddit
> - Gamedev.net
> - Did you already search with your favorite search engine to see if your question has been asked/answered elsewhere?
> - Are you simply looking for someone to make a decision for you? Are you suffering from analysis paralysis? Just make a choice and go with it, see where it takes you. Or perhaps you could roll some dice or flip a coin.

With

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Game Development Stack Exchange, it may be [on topic for another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

In this specific case, your question could be a good fit for [Software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Please read the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure it fits well and to see how you should ask there.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on a point addressed by Alexandre Vaillancourt, your question *might* be on-topic for [the Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Of particular note, here are some more considerations:

- The site features [a game-development tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development?sort=newest). The tag currently has a response rate of roughly 60%, and the top user appears to be active.
- In contrast with most other sites, there does not appear to be any specific hard coded off-topic close reason *unique* to that site. Most sites have a couple of options under *"Flag" > "Should be closed because.." > "Off-topic because.."* that can give you a good idea of some common unique close reasons. Software Recommendation currently only has the option of *"Blatantly off-topic"*.
- You can read more about [what not to ask](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to remain on-topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at their help center, which might give you a greater idea if this is the right avenue.
- [The tour page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) specifically states that a good question should have a *purpose* (i.e. what it is you are trying to accomplish) and some *objective requirements* (i.e. the minimum set of features you require from the software).
- In contrast, [the tour page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) specifically states that questions that do not define a set purpose or objective requirements are considered *off-topic*.

---

All in all, looking at your question, I am confidant it could easily be adapted to be appropriate for [the Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

There are suggestions in the help center: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (see the section headed "Where can I ask subjective, discussion, and other questions not fit for this site?")